# BlockSchemes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, components, visualization

I need visualizer of `algorithms` created in JavaScript. Like BlockSchemes, mostly with If and Statement blocks. That could be moved, resized, connected with arrows. Anybody know such open source projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to drawing with JavaScript the only two things I can think of are the HTML Canvas Tag which is HTML 5 OR having an Image Handler and using CSS positioning which is not drawing with JavaScript but simply positioning to give a drawing affect through the use of AJAX

Comment: Its not drawing, its positioning of general tags, but I was thinking, something like this already exist, maybe in Flash?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what it is exactly you require from your question.  Can you explain more?

Comment: There is gmail - outlook in web, I want Visio in Web.

Comment: Thanks, but its commercial and priority to JavaScript solutions, not Flash

Answer (score 0):

I am using Org Chart from [Google Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) - it is a JavaScript library, that can draw tree-like graph. It can be used for lot of data, i am using it a lot for if-statement tree like structures.

Unfortunately, the result is static, cannot be moved or resized.